# how disable my lockscreen on unchecking my checkbox

Tags: android, lockscreen

I have sucessfully implemented my lockscreen with puzzle image it is worlikng completely fine  but now i want to disable lockscreen when the user unchecks this checkbox and enable if user checks the checkbox
Say me how to do it
My lockscreen code

```
 public class LockscreenService extends Service {
private LinearLayout linearLayout;
private WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams;
private WindowManager windowManager;
String p;
ImageView img,aimg;
final ArrayList<Bitmap> beforeshuffle = new ArrayList<>(9);
final ArrayList<Bitmap> aftershuffle = new ArrayList<>(9);
ArrayList<Bitmap> smallimages = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(9);
GridView grid;
Bitmap bs;
Bitmap as;
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
BroadcastReceiver screenReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) && linearLayout == null) {
            init();
        }
    }
};
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    registerReceiver(screenReceiver, intentFilter);
    windowManager = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE));
    layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
}
private void init() {
    linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    windowManager.addView(linearLayout, layoutParams);
    ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.lockscreen, linearLayout);
    //   View btnClose = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.button);
    img = (ImageView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.bs);
    aimg = (ImageView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.as);
    grid = (GridView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    Globalvariable c=new Globalvariable();
    bs=c.giveBitmap();

    String p="/data/user/0/com.example.user.myapplication/app_imageDir/profile.jpg";
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(),p,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("path",p);
    String bspath="/data/user/0/com.example.user.myapplication/app_Beforeshuffle/beforeshuffle";





    bs=loadImageFromStorage(bspath);

    // Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) i.getParcelableExtra("bitmap");

    //smallimage_Numbers is to tell how many smallimage_s the image should split

    int smallimage_Numbers = 9;

    //Getting the source image to split

    //  ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.source_image);
    // File imgFile = new  File("profile.jpg"

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(p);
    splitImage(myBitmap, smallimage_Numbers);
    View btnClose = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.button8);
    btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            img.setImageBitmap(bs);
            as=getBitmapFromView(grid);
            aimg.setImageBitmap(as);
            Bitmap a=getBitmapFromView(img);
            Bitmap b=getBitmapFromView(aimg);
            img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            aimg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // do something when the corky3 is clicked
            if(b.sameAs(a) ){
            //    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"CORRECT",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ///Intent service = new Intent(LockscreenService.this, calculator.class);
               // startService(service);
                Intent service = new Intent(LockscreenService.this, caclservice.class);
                startService(service);
               // windowManager.removeView(linearLayout);
               // linearLayout = null;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("jhgeiugh","jhgfeug");
               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"WRONG",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

my lockscreen me[image: my checknox in lockscreen menu]nu

In this image there is checkbox and i need to know what i have to do when user clicks it

Code with Shared preference

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    sharedPreferences =getSharedPreferences(mypreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
CustomList adapter = new
        CustomList(this, web, imageId);
list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.List);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
        final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cb);
        if (position == 1) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChangePassword.class));
        } else if (position == 2) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Changephoto.class));
        } else if (position == 4) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Puzzle.class));
        } else if (position == 5) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), choosephoto.class));
        }



    }
});

    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {

            if(isChecked){
                Log.d("ghjk", "ghfu");
                sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(name1, "true");
                editor.commit();
                cb.setChecked(true);
                KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
                KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
                lock.reenableKeyguard();
            }else {
                sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(name1, "false");
                editor.commit();
                KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
                KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
                lock.reenableKeyguard();
            }
        }
    });

    if(sharedPreferences.contains(name1)){
        String b=sharedPreferences.getString(name1,"");
        Log.d("dsf",b);
        if(b.equals("true")) {
           cb.setChecked(true);
        }else
        {
            cb.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what you have to do is, save some value in shared preferences when that checkbox is checked/unchecked. Then check that value to enable/disable your service

Comment: disable means wat you mean? if you want disable/enable feature of puzzle protect over lock screen simply start/stop the service on checkbox toggle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem as said by  @ashwin stored a flag in checkbox and checked that flag value to unregister the Broadcast receiver like this

```
    BroadcastReceiver screenReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean b = sp.getBoolean(name4, false);
        if(b)
        {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) && linearLayout == null) {
                init();
            }

        }else
            unregisterReceiver(screenReceiver);

    }
};
```